# Redis StreamMessageListenerContainer dont reconnect on redis server restart

Tags: java, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis, redis-streams

I have implemented StreamMessageListenerContainer to consume and process message from Redis Stream.

I am using Lettuce Connection factory.

While my application is deployed, I restart Redis server and my StreamMessageListenerContainer stops consuming messages from stream.

```
StreamMessageListenerContainer<string, objectrecord<string, book> 
 streamMessageListenerContainer =
                StreamMessageListenerContainer.create(redisConnectionFactory, options);
        
 String streamKey = Cosntants.STREAM_KEY_001;
 
 streamMessageListenerContainer.receiveAutoAck(Consumer.from("group-b", "consumer-a"),
                StreamOffset.create(streamKey, ReadOffset.lastConsumed()), 
                new AsyncConsumeStreamListener("Consumption group consumption B", 
                "group-b", "consumer-bb"));
```

Any inputs on what might be going wrong ?

Comment: You need to detect disconnect and reconnect yourself

Comment: Use autoReconnect(true) in client options

Comment: @AsadAwadia do you mean on lettuce client options? I have already set it true.

Comment: LettuceConnection factory reconnects successfully, I just face issue with StreamListener. By the way how to reconnect StreamMessageListener?